Можно ли парсить данные с таблицы excel по ссылке и редактировать ее?
Я использую библиотеку pandas, которая просто работает с файлом xlsx и с этим нет проблем локально, но можно ли сделать, чтобы она брала данные из таблицы по ссылке и могла ее редактировать?

Редактировать - смотря что. Если просто данные без разметки, то можно. Но в разметку Pandas не умеет. А по ссылке - ну, можно скачать. Вопрос как потом обратно залить. Что за ссылка то? HTTP?

Вы используете гугл таблицы или у вас просто где-то на хостинге валяется файл?

Все решилось, спасибо. Стоило изначально воспользоваться Google Sheets.
